# Necesito pasar esta consulta a laravel

Tags: laravel

Necesito pasar esta consulta a laravel

[image: Captura de pantalla consulta mySql]

select p.nombre ,e.fecha_hora ,e.num_comprobante ,SUM(d1.valor * d1.cantidad) as agua ,SUM(d2.valor * d2.cantidad) as fiestas ,SUM(d.valor * d.cantidad) as otros ,e.total_especie from especie e join persona p on e.idcliente = p.idpersona left join detalle_especie d1 on e.idEspecie = d1.idEspecie and d1.idImpuesto = 1 left join detalle_especie d2 on e.idEspecie = d2.idEspecie and d2.idImpuesto = 2 left join detalle_especie d on e.idEspecie = d.idEspecie and d.idImpuesto > 2 group by e.num_comprobante;

$especies = DB::table('especie as e')
                  ->leftjoin('detalle_especie as d', 'e.idEspecie', '=', 'd.idEspecie')->AND ('d.idImpuesto', '=', '1')

```
          //  ->leftjoin('detalle_especie as d', 'e.idEspecie', '=', 'd.idEspecie', '||','d.idImpuesto', '=', '0' )
            ->select('fecha_hora', 
                    'num_comprobante', 
                    'total_especie', 
                   DB::raw ('SUM(d.valor * d.cantidad) as otros')) 


            ->groupby('num_comprobante')
            ->get();
```

// dd($especies); 
 $data = [
        "especies" => $especies

```
];

return view('reportes.index', $data);
```

Comment: El código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: además añade si estas usando algún modelo o si vas a usar el query Builder?

Comment: select  p.nombre
    ,e.fecha_hora
    ,e.num_comprobante
    ,SUM(d1.valor * d1.cantidad) as agua
    ,SUM(d2.valor * d2.cantidad) as fiestas
    ,SUM(d.valor * d.cantidad) as otros
    ,e.total_especie
from especie  e
  join persona p on e.idcliente = p.idpersona
  left join detalle_especie d1 on e.idEspecie = d1.idEspecie and d1.idImpuesto = 1
  left join detalle_especie d2 on e.idEspecie = d2.idEspecie and d2.idImpuesto = 2
  left join detalle_especie d on e.idEspecie = d.idEspecie and d.idImpuesto > 2
group by  e.num_comprobante;

Comment: Tu código esta mal formateado para leerlo, arréglalo para facilitar la lectura del mismo. Mientras, como no especificas como hacerla o que estas usando te dejo una respuesta mas abajo.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer no especificas como realizar la consulta, asi que...

Agrega esto:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

y la consulta, para no complicarte mucho puedes usarlo de esta forma:

```
$resultado = DB::select('select p.nombre ,e.fecha_hora ,e.num_comprobante ,SUM(d1.valor * d1.cantidad) as agua ,SUM(d2.valor * d2.cantidad) as fiestas ,SUM(d.valor * d.cantidad) as otros ,e.total_especie from especie e join persona p on e.idcliente = p.idpersona left join detalle_especie d1 on e.idEspecie = d1.idEspecie and d1.idImpuesto = 1 left join detalle_especie d2 on e.idEspecie = d2.idEspecie and d2.idImpuesto = 2 left join detalle_especie d on e.idEspecie = d.idEspecie and d.idImpuesto > 2 group by e.num_comprobante');
```

Bueno,el código es el que usas, pero como ya mencioné no es muy legible. dentro de las comillas usas tu consulta tal y como es. Aunque lo mas optimo seria que uses los modelos. Luego usas el resultado de la forma que necesites.

Comment: Buen aporte sin embargo esto deja muy de lado todo el poder de Eloquent y/o de los métodos con ayuda del query builder, por que por ejemplo si existen los métodos join y left join